# Animate an element which is already being animated

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have a jQuery animation with a bubble rising up from the bottom of the screen while at the same time going form 0 opacity to 100 opacity.

I want to make another function which causes the bubble to disappear if its clicked.

Will this cause a problem? Should I reference the first function within the second and command it to stop? If so can you post a code sample of stopping an occurring animation function.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("elements").stop();
$("elements").animate( ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

A little pseudo code:

```
$("#bubble").animate({
    top: 0,
    opacity: 1
}, 2000);

$("#bubble").on('click', function() {
     $(this).stop(true, true).hide();
});
```

To stop the animated element just use [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), and to hide it you could use [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Comment: What is (true, ture)?... could I say make opacity animation stop while allowing the top animation to continue with (false, true)?

Comment: No, I'm afraid you can't do that. `.stop( [clearQueue] [, jumpToEnd] )` so if the first one is true, it clears the queue, and if the second is true, the animation jumps to the end.